# Adding multiple known_hosts entries at once

Tags: ssh, parallel-ssh

Is there a way to add multiple known_host entries at once, as a one-time thing.

Because I don't want to disable SSH Host Key verification which is terrible practice.

I just want to have a "prep" step at the beginning, add them all at once, then go on with using parallel-ssh.

I checked the `ssh-keyscan` and `parallel-ssh` manuals but didn't find a built-in option.

Answer (score 0):

I finally created that one-line solution:

```
grep -h "" my_hosts | xargs ssh-keyscan > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That will generate the keys of all the hosts in file my_hosts to `known_hosts`.

And `parallel-ssh` can work as such after:

```
parallel-ssh -H my_hosts
```